# what is the meaning of {assm} Windows command script

Tags: windows, windows-scripting

I am looking in to a **test.cmd** file. In that i saw a line

```
SET sassm="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\{smartassembly}\{smartassembly}.com"
echo %sassm%
```

output is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\{smartassembly}\{smartassembly}.com"
```

i did not understand the meaning of **'{smartassembly}'** in Windows command script.

Comment: Assembely language script? For the processor? Maybe its just a requirement before calling assembely code so that script knows to set up needed prerequisites for running. (Just guessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything. [The program's name is `{smartassembly}`](http://download.cnet.com/smartassembly/3000-10250_4-10503439.html) with the curly braces.